# How to start two J2ME Midlets on Mac OS X with WTK 3.0.

Tags: java, java-me, midlet, java-wireless-toolkit

Whenever I want to start second Midlet, I get error

> MIDlet suite is already running.

I'm developing under Netbeans.

On Windows it work OK.

Comment: you want to start second emulator , is it ?

Comment: Does it *have* to be 3.0? Version 2.5.2_01 seems much better and should work without problems.

Comment: @BlaXpirit It must be there in 3.0 too, Let us first clearly understand your question mruffa

Comment: to *org.life.java*: What have you just said?

Comment: Hey. Yes, I want to start new emulator to test multiplayer game - I need at least 2 "users to play". @BlaXpirit : i can't use 2.5.2 on a Mac OS X.

Comment: @BlaXpirit I meant,I asked mruffa to clearify his/her question. First part of comment was for you.

Comment: to just test you can start it in micro emulator and another instance is default instance of WTK.

Answer (score 0):

you have to choose a different phone or emulator from the project properties
while you're running the first emulator.