# How to run two Java ME emulators concurrently on Mac OSX

Tags: java, java-me, midlet

I'm developing a mobile application in Netbeans, but I'm running into problems when testing communication using SMS. In order to test this, I obviously need two emulators running, which I'm aware should be as easy as running the project twice, but on Mac OSX I'm given the error "MIDlet suite is already running.".

I've tried to research this problem as best as possible, but there isn;t a lot of information on it available online. The best I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014079/how-to-start-two-j2me-midlets-on-mac-os-x-with-wtk-3-0) another Stack Overflow question with the same problem that never got a satisfactory answer, so I'm asking again in the hope that someone will have a better idea of how to deal with this by now.

Answer (score 2):

In NetBeans, you must change the main project before starting the second one: Run/Set main project/... then the second project will start in the same emulator window as the first one. You will be able to switch between the running midlets in the emulator.

Furthermore, if you change the project configuration (phone model) before starting the second project, you will get two emulator windows with different phone numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Getting two emulators to run at the same time in NetBeans:

Run your application with one run configuration,

i.e. Default `CldcPhone1`, and then change the configuration,
either at the project settings.

Or next to the run button, and set up to another emulator,
Ie. Default `CldcPhone1` and run again.

The two emulators will run together simultaneously, and you can interact between them.